# Exclude package / directory from SonarQube's 'Package Tangle Index' analisys

Tags: maven, sonarqube, sonar-runner, sonarqube-4.0

We run SonarQube analisys on our code and we're having a bad time with a 3rd party package and the "Package Tangle Index" analisys. For some reasons we can't fix those issues and I can't simply exclude the folder from being processed because that would be too harsh; I have another rules I want to run there.

So... is there any way to exclude this package / directory from being analyzed on the specific Package Tangle Index rule ? We've already tried `squid:CycleBetweenPackages` on the rule exclusions but it didn't seem to work. The alerts are not generated but the index is still there going strong.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Package Tangle Index is not a rule, it is actually a metric, so you could not delete it.

The metrics are always calculated because they are used to activate or not the rules.

In SonarQube 4.5.1 (version I use), you could do was delete this package of analysis. However, all would be excluded, ie no other metric would be calculated for it: Settings > Exclusions> Files.

Comment: Thanks for your answer Marlon! Like I said I can't exclude the whole package because I have some rules and metrics I'd like to be analyzed.